# Open and close bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[GIF PART 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHuUW.gif)

[GIF PART 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuJnw.gif)

Hi guys,
does anyone know how to do make a bootstrap modal popup exactly like the one on the GIF image above,
I tried already but it didn't work.
**My JS Code:**

```js
$('#abtn').click(function(){
    $('#aaa').modal('show');
    $('#bbb').modal('hide');
});
$('#bbtn').click(function(){
    $('#bbb').modal('show');
    $('#aaa').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Both GIFs look identical. Describe the difference in words.

Comment: @WebDevBooster Hi, I am trying to make. For ex: When I click buttonA, its toggle modalA. While modalA is still toggle open, when I click buttonB, it should automatic close modalA & toggle modalB.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @WebDevBooster hi, I am using bootstrap v3.0.0 & for jquery is v2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look like this, but I don't think that the `position: fixed` requirement to make them stay as visible as the modals will be worth it. You should probably reconsider this idea.

```js
$('#abtn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    $('#aaa').modal('show');
});
$('#bbtn').click(function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    $('#bbb').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="abtn" style="position: fixed; z-index: 2000;">AAA</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="bbtn" style="position: fixed; left: 4rem; z-index: 2000;">BBBB</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="aaa" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aaaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="aaaLabel">AAAAA</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        AAAAAAAA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="bbb" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bbbLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="bbbLabel">BBBBB</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        BBBBBBB
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ,You are a god.Thanks alot man! , This is what I was looking for.  The solution looks simple but very hard to solve .

Comment: You're welcome. I just needed some css fiddling to figure it out, is all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
    $("#myBtn1").click(function(){
        $("#myModal1").modal();
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">aaa</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>you clicked aaa</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn1">bbb</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>you clicked bbb</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Vicky, thanks for the answer but this isnt the one that I was looking for. I want to bring both of the button in front of the modal so that when I click each of the toggle button, It's shows the latest modal and close the previous one